# clickable JS functions after PHP+Ajax innerHTML not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, innerhtml

First off: I do not want to use JQuery, i know it would make it easier but it would ravish the porpuse of the thing.
Note: ajaxFunction is the default ajax exemple for a GET/POST

Now, after clicking the function, the first time, it does work and everyrhing gets replaced by the php-echo. The problem is AFTER.

After changing the initia-div ("login-place") to the next div ("regit") the javascript function of sregit.onClick = function() does not work.

How do i go around this? Should i create the DOMElement in PHP and use xmlSave("index.php")?

initial-div:

```
<div id="login-place">
    <table id="login-init" name="login-init">
    <tr>
        <td>username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="user" id="user" /></td>
        <td>password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="login" id="login" type="button" value="entrar" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

the JS code:

```
            var slogin = document.getElementById("login");
            slogin.onclick = function() {
                //alert("inside."+user.value);
                s = "goforth=1&user="+user.value+"&pass="+pass.value;
                ajaxFunction('4',""+s); 
            }

            var sregit = document.getElementById("regit");
            sregit.onclick = function () {
                alert("inside."+user.value);
                s = "regit=1&user="+user.value+"&pass="+pass.value;
                ajaxfunction('4',""+s); 
            }
    function ajaxFunction(arg,string) {
      var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
      if(xmlhttp) {

          if (arg==4) {
            nextland = "login-place";
            document.getElementById("all-burps").innerHTML=string;
            xmlhttp.open("POST","session.php",true);
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        if (arg==4) {
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-length', string.length);
            xmlhttp.send(""+string); 
        }
        }
    }
function handleServerResponse() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
     if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
       if (nextland != "login-place") { document.getElementById(nextland).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; } //Update the HTML Form element
       else {
           // alert(xmlhttp.responseText); -> this is true no error up here.
           var thediv = document.getElementById("login-init"); 
           thediv.parentNode.removeChild(thediv); //this happens fine.
           var theplace = document.getElementById("login-place");
           var thelement = document.createElement("div"); //this too.
           thelement.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  //this too'
           theplace.appendChild(thelement); //this too.

       }
     }
```

And, the innerhtml.responseText is =

```
        echo '
            <table id="login-2" name="login-2">
            <h3>o username ' . $username . ' não existe. <a href="#" id="register-link" name="register-link">Queres registar?</a></h3>
            <tr>
                <td>username</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="' . $username . '"/></td>
            <td>password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="' . $password . '" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="entrar" id="regit" name="regit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        ';
```

I hope this is enough for anyone to understand my doubt. else i'll reword it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call in the function that does not work says `ajaxfunction`, whereas the function is called `ajaxFunction` - Javascript is case sensitive.

Also, you need to move the declaration of the `onclick` function for `regit` to inside the `handleServerResponse()` function, after the line `thelement.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;`, because before this line is called, there is no element with `id="regit"`, so the binding of the function won't work.

Also, you should terminate the functions declared as `element.onclick = function () {}` with a `;`. Declaring functions in this manner is an assignment **statement** and as such it requires a semi-colon to terminate it.

**EDIT** here is your code reworked so hopefully it does what you want, with some extra bloat removed. I am assuming that `xmlhttp`, `nextland`, `user` and `pass` have been declared in some code you haven't posted - have they?

```
document.getElementById("login").onclick = function() {
  //alert("inside."+user.value);
  var s = "goforth=1&user="+encodeURIComponent(user.value)+"&pass="+encodeURIComponent(pass.value);
  ajaxFunction(4, s); 
};

function ajaxFunction(arg, string) {
  //var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
  // ...but never actually *used* anywhere...
  if (xmlhttp) {
    if (arg == 4) {
      nextland = "login-place";
      document.getElementById("all-burps").innerHTML = string;
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "session.php", true);
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    if (arg == 4) {
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-length', string.length);
      xmlhttp.send(string); 
    }
  }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
  var theplace, thelement;
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      if (nextland != "login-place") {
        // Update the HTML Form element
        document.getElementById(nextland).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      } else {
        // Remove the old div and add the new content
        theplace = document.getElementById("login-place");
        theplace.removeChild(document.getElementById("login-init"));
        thelement = document.createElement("div");
        thelement.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        theplace.appendChild(thelement); //this too.
        // Now add the click handler
        document.getElementById("regit").onclick = function() {
          // alert("inside."+user.value);
          var s = "regit=1&user="+encodeURIComponent(user.value)+"&pass="+encodeURIComponent(pass.value);
          ajaxfunction(4, s); 
        };
      }
    } else {
      // Handle HTTP errors
      alert('HTTP ' + xmlhttp.status);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot imagine how much love and tenderness i have for you right now. Thanks for the "Javascript IS case sensitive" i bet that'd take another hour to find out.
Also, it makes total sense that i should assign a statement to something after it exists. Thank you Kindly, there aren't enough words for the time you took off my head.

Comment: You shouldn't :) Yep, they were all set before.
Also, i learnt a new function today encodeURIComponent :P
And what have you done with my code? That neat text block couldn't possibly be the same code as i have xD [the bloat wasn't bloat, there were more args :P]

Answer (score 1):

Try to call

"sregit.onclick = function () { .... "

after appending content in handleServerResponse() function. When you call it earlier, no action is binded, because there is no #regit element in DOM.

Comment: I GAVE YOU YOUR FIRST POINT! HUZZAH :D

Answer (score 0):

The onClick events are lost when you modify the HTML like that. You'll have to re-add the onClick events each time you replace the HTML or use the onClick inline like `onclick="something()"`.

You also have a syntax error, you're using a lowercase F in `ajaxfunction('4',""+s);`, whereas the function is named `ajaxFunction`.